# How could I make two different onClick events into onc

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have defined two different  functions to a onClick event separately, how could I make then into one single onClick event. Here is what I have so far:

```
const playPause = (props) => {
    
    let audio = new Audio(project)
    const start = () => {
      audio.play()  
    }
    const  stop = () => {
           audio.pause()
    }  
    return(
        <div>
        <button onClick={start}>Play</button>
        <button onClick={stop}>Pause</button>        
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have tried to declare a function that contains this two functions like:

const playThanStop {
return stop ? start : stop
}
//so it could return on single:

```
 <button onClick={playThanStop}>Play/Pause</button>
```

but that did not work, any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with separate handlers? Also you probably don't want to declare your `audio` variable as a top-level variable as it will be redeclared on every render.

Comment: If you want a single handler you need to be identify the buttons. Maybe stick a data attribute on each one and then pick them up in the function: `const { id } = e.target.dataset;`, for example

Comment: You could refer to [`audio.paused`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/paused), but React won't notice the state change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use virtual dom it will help you

```
let song=document.getElementById("ad");
function togglePlayPause()
{
    song.paused ? song.play() : song.pause();
}
```

Comment: `song.pause` is always thruthy

Comment: song.paused will work

Comment: iI did, thanks much appreciate it!